# Capacitors in series

Tags: capacitance

Okay so I'm looking at RF designs and I've come across a couple of designs which need 2p2 caps.

I've seen

C1.C2/C1+C2

being plugged into a function (the tank part of the circuit) which gives a lower capacitance for the circuit i.e. C1 && C2 == 27pf (gives 13.5pf if tap taken between C1 and C2)

My question is this:

Lets say I have    + 10pf ->|-> 10pf -> 10pf

Where | is the tap does that mean I can somehow get a lower capacitance by tapping in a series of caps? (please show me the equation if poss :))

Comment: and I don't have 2p2 caps...

Comment: Didn't you provide the equation already by yourself? Do you have difficulties to apply your equation to 3 caps or more in series?

Comment: @PetPaulsen 27*27/27+27 = 13.5 (half the caps value) 10*10*10/30 = 33.3??? It's late and I'm sh*t at maths.

Comment: Now Im thinking about it I have to do something to do with the tap point and its percentage of the overall capacitance i.e. 1/3 in the 10+10+10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capacitors in series are like resistors in parallel, to get the total capacitance add the reciprocals, then take the reciprocal of the result.
For example, if we have 20pF, 10pF, and 5pF caps, the total capacitance would be:

1 / ((1 / 20pF) + (1 / 10pF) + (1 / 5pF)) = 2.857pF

For two capacitors you can use the (C1 * C2) / (C1 + C2) but this won't work for 3 or more.

```
                 20pF 10pF 5pF
Connect here -> -||---||---||- <- and here

                    2.857pF
Equivalent to:  ------||------
```

Note that putting multiple caps in series probably won;t work very well at such a low value (there will be extra unwanted inductance which will lower the resonant frequency)
2.2pF is actually a very common value, for example Farnell has 46 options under [RF caps](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202460%20110046248&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202460&mm=1000002%7C%7C,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202460&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202460) and 94 options under [ceramic caps](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202740%20110046248&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202740&mm=1000002%7C%7C,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202740&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202740). I advise picking one of these.

Comment: ... So are you telling me that by just putting them in series actually lowers the combined capacitance Oli? i.e. where do I tap or do I just take it off 'the end' + C1 -> C2 -> C3 - ... do I tap?

Comment: Yes, putting them in series will lower the total capacitance. You connect at either end (i.e. free lead of C1, and free lead of C3)

Comment: @PaulSullivan - see bad attempt at ascii art, hopefully it's clear enough ;-)

Comment: Hahah thanks Oli - your ascii art is a much appreciated hark back to my c64 and earlier days - marked as answer and see I need to go back to text books. It's a bit counter intuitive really as I expected greater dielectric surface area to = more capacitance.

Comment: AHHHH! Now I see there are only so many charge carriers to each side of each part of the capacitor so thts why its reduced... obvious when I get my brain in gear! (I think...) Why does this happen?!?

Comment: If you think about it, the way to get greater surface area is to put them in parallel (in parallel = bigger total plate area) Have a look at the edit for source of 2.2pF caps, I'd go for a single cap for RF purposes.

Comment: You could try some in series and see how it goes (might as well while you're waiting for the others to arrive), just be aware it's not the "ideal" solution. How it affects things depends on the circuit, it may be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You already provided the formula to calculate the capacitance of two capacitors in series:
$$C_{1,2}=\frac{C_1 \cdot C_2}{C_1+C_2}$$

When you want to apply the formula to three capacitors (\$C_1, C_2, C_3\$) in series, think it this way:
Combine the capacitors in groups of two. First calculate
$$C_{1,2} = \frac{C_1 \cdot C_2}{C_1+C_2}$$
then calculate as if you have a capacitor with capacitance \$C_{1,2}\$ and \$C_3\$ in series:
$$C_{1,2,3} = \frac{C_{1,2}\cdot C_3}{C_{1,2}+C_3}$$

So for your example of 3 capacitors each 10pF:
$$C_{1,2} = 5pF = \frac{C_1 \cdot C_2}{C_1+C_2} = \frac{10pF \cdot 10pF}{10pF+10pF}$$
$$C_{1,2,3} = 3.33pF = \frac{C_{1,2}\cdot C_3}{C_{1,2}+C_3} = \frac{10pF \cdot 5pF}{10pF+5pF}$$

Comment: Thanks Paul - I thought your answer was clearer but Oli used the textbook reciprocal route